multicast from loopback device to nic
am trying to test UDP mutlicast in same host.since i have only 1 NIC card,my idea is send multicast data to loopback device and consume at NIC
googling how to send multicast data to loopback device ,i got below commands
ifconfig lo multicast
ip route add 239.0.0.2 dev lo
route add -net 224.0.0.0 netmask 240.0.0.0 dev lo
ifconfig lo multicast

below are the sample applications
sender.c
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    const int delay_secs = 0;
    const char *message2 = "Hello, World!";

    unsigned long counter = 0;

    char message[8192] = {0};

    int fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (fd < 0)
    {
        perror("socket(1)");
        return 1;
    }

    struct ip_mreq mreq;
    memset(&mreq, 0, sizeof(mreq));
    mreq.imr_interface.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.2.6"); 

    if (
        setsockopt(
            fd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_IF, (char *)&mreq, sizeof(mreq)) < 0)
    {
        perror("setsockopt(1)");
        return 1;
    }

    char loopch = 1;

        if(setsockopt(fd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_LOOP, (char *)&loopch, sizeof(loopch)) < 0)
        {
        perror("setsockopt(2)");
        return 1;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("239.0.0.2");
    addr.sin_port = htons(1234);

    while (1)
    {
        char ch = 0;
        int len=snprintf(message, 8192, "%s-%lu", message2, ++counter);
        message[len]='\0';
        int nbytes = sendto(
            fd,
            message,
            len,
            0,
            (struct sockaddr *)&addr,
            sizeof(addr));
        if (nbytes < 0)
        {
            perror("sendto");
            return 1;
        }
        sleep(delay_secs);
    }

    return 0;
}



listner.c

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <time.h>

#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MSGBUFSIZE 8192

int main()
{
    int fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (fd < 0)
    {
        perror("socket");
        return 1;
    }

    u_int yes = 1;
    if (
        setsockopt(
            fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&yes, sizeof(yes)) < 0)
    {
        perror("Reusing ADDR failed");
        return 1;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("239.0.0.2"); 
    addr.sin_port = htons(1234);

    if (bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0)
    {
        perror("bind");
        return 1;
    }

    struct ip_mreq mreq;
    mreq.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = inet_addr("239.0.0.2");
    mreq.imr_interface.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.2.6"); //local wifi address
    if (
        setsockopt(
            fd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, (char *)&mreq, sizeof(mreq)) < 0)
    {
        perror("setsockopt");
        return 1;
    }

    while (1)
    {
        char msgbuf[MSGBUFSIZE];
        int addrlen = sizeof(addr);
        int nbytes = recvfrom(
            fd,
            msgbuf,
            MSGBUFSIZE,
            0,
            (struct sockaddr *)&addr,
            &addrlen);
        if (nbytes < 0)
        {
            perror("recvfrom");
            return 1;
        }
        msgbuf[nbytes] = '\0';
        puts(msgbuf);
    }

    return 0;
}


what exactly is going wrong here.am trying to test in my personal setup which runs ubuntu.

Aside: nice alternative to struct ip_mreq mreq; memset(&mreq, 0, sizeof(mreq)); is struct ip_mreq mreq = { 0 }; (or C2X struct ip_mreq mreq = {  };.

From a debug point of view, consider replacing puts(msgbuf); with something more informative like printf("%3d <%.*s>\n",  nbytes, nbytes, msgbuf);. (length , length limit and sentinels).  Please post the output seen.

@chux-ReinstateMonica modifed sender.

message[len]='\0'; is not needed.  snprintf() already appends a null character.  It is bad when len == -1 or 8192 or more.  Code does not even need to append a null character  in preparation for sendto().

Best not to change code once answers begin to arrive.  If needed append code.  Please post ouptut seen.

Sending to 239.1.0.0 and receiving at 239.0.0.2?

@igmartin sorry i later edited the code and copied.i will make it proper,sending and recieving both to 239.0.0.2 itself

If you join the loopback interface on the sender side with setsockopt(fd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, ...), the mreq struct containing the multicast group and "lo"and set the forwarding interface to "lo", the the Linux kernel will accept the datagram and replicate it to the other sockets that are subscribed to the group, including the receiver on the Wi-Fi interface. Works for me on Linux unlike in MacOS/BSD

The Linux kernel will not accept an incoming multicast datagram on a given interface (e.g loopback) if there are no active subscriptions on that interface. Once the mcast packet is accepted, the kernel will replicate the packet to all sockets that have joined the group, no matter in which interface.
If you add a join("239.0.0.2", "127.0.0.1") in sender and set the forwarding interface to "127.0.0.1" then listener will receive on the wi-fi interface
Moreover, if in sender you bind to ("192.168.2.39", 0) then you will receive the packets with source address  "192.168.2.39"

@igmartin i will try joining mcast group in sender and verify

msgbuf[nbytes] = '\0'; may be a buffer overflow.
(Although that is not apparent given OP's short strings, yet it remains UB with a full message.)
Perhaps something to leave room for the later appended null character.
recvfrom() returns number of bytes received.
  int nbytes = recvfrom(fd, msgbuf, 
    // MSGBUFSIZE,
    MSGBUFSIZE - 1,
    0, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, &addrlen);

Or skip appending a null character and use "%.*s" to print the character array.
// msgbuf[nbytes] = '\0';
// puts(msgbuf);
printf("%.*s\n", nbytes, msgbuf);

or directly (which has some benefit if a null character was read.)
// msgbuf[nbytes] = '\0';
// puts(msgbuf);
fwrite(msgbuf, 1, nbytes, stdout);
putchar('\n');

...

when the sender pushes data to NIC,listner recieves properly.dont thing NULL is the issue here

@Nagaraj Do you see than if recvfrom() received in msgbuf[] the maximum size of data, 8192, and then nbytes == 8192, then msgbuf[nbytes] = '\0'; is a buffer overflow?

in sender if i change 127.0.0.1 to 192.168,2,6,data is received properly in listener
but this is not i wanted,sending and receiving at same NIC
My requirement is send to one device and consume on other.since i have only 1 network device,am trying to send to loopback device and consume at NIC
